# Select top level children using CSS

Tags: css

Is it possible to select all top level children regardless of their type using CSS.

> ```
> <div class="parent"> <div class="top-level-1">
>  <!-- CONTENT -->
> </div>
> <div class="top-level-2">
>  <!-- CONTENT -->
> </div>
> <a class="top-level-3">
>  <!-- CONTENT -->
> </a> </div>
> ```

When I use,

```
.parent * {}
```

it selects the child elements but also elements within that child.

What I want to do is,

1. Select **ONLY** the top level child elements (in the sample code above - div.top-level-1, div.top-level-2 and a.top-level-3)
2. Classes will not be the same therefore a solution where classes are not used is preferred.

**Here is the JSFiddle for better understanding:** http://jsfiddle.net/Q4BBd/

Comment: why not `.parent div {}`

Comment: @TigOldBitties There is an anchor in the top level which I want to select as well. The top level children can be from different types not only divs.

Comment: @user3607282: Your question not clear. Can you please described a bit more:)

Comment: @user3607282: Means you want to select all three child divs (div.top-level-1, div.top-level-2 and a.top-level-3) but not select their child?

Comment: @IshanJain That's correct.

Comment: @user3607282: Ok, I update my answer according your requirement. (You can check)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the [`>` combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) to select only immediate children (of any type) of a top-level `<div>`:

```
body > div > * {}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/heQLm/)

Comment: Nope, in this solution if you add an element inside a child that will also get selected. Updated Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/heQLm/1/

Comment: That's not being affected by the selection, it's just inheriting it's parents `color`. Check: http://jsfiddle.net/heQLm/2/ See how the selection is last but doesn't change the `<span>`?

Answer (score 0):

> div.parent > *:first-child {color:red}

This Will work for you

`Js fiddle:`[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SiddharthShah/heQLm/3/)

Comment: @user3607282 have you check this solution?

Comment: it only applies to the first child. :(

Comment: Again, that will select child elements within child elements as well. I only want to select the first level of child elements.

Comment: First Level of Child elements of .parent? then div.parent > *:first-child {color:red} http://jsfiddle.net/SiddharthShah/heQLm/3/

Answer (score 0):

you can use this.

```
.parent > div {
   /*CSS goes here*/
}
```

Comment: No classes can vary. I'm looking for a solution where we don't use class names to select.

Comment: In that case you can use .parent > div

Comment: @Tushar You should probably update your answer to that ;) Your answer doesn't answer the question, but that comment of yours does.

Comment: Its Updated :)...hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would help you:

a) Select all divs:

```
div{color:black;}
```

b) Find any divs that are inside of `.parent` divs (OR direct child of the `.parent`)

```
.parent > * {
    color:red;
}
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/H8Pw7/5/)